# Working out an average on time

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find out the best way to do an average on time (basically call times I want to find out the average)

The data is coming from a datatable that i'm looping through. I can't quite work out how to use a TimeSpan though, what can I convert the string from / to to pass it through like I have below?

```
TimeSpan total = default(TimeSpan);

foreach (DataRow row in dtChats.Rows)
{
    total += row["TotalTime"].ToString();
}

TimeSpan myAverage = total / dtChats.Rows.Count;
```

Edit:

Sorry, row['TotalTime'] is a time value such as 0:05:44 representing 5mins 44 seconds

Comment: Do you really need to use `TimeSpan` at all?  What does `row["TotalTime"]` look like?

Comment: what does the data in row["TotalTime"] look like? is it a string? is it milliseconds?

Comment: Sorry, row['TotalTime'] is a time value such as 0:05:44 representing 5mins 44 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a LINQ version, I'm sure it can be improved:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("TotalTime", typeof(string));
 dt.Rows.Add("00:05:44");
 dt.Rows.Add("00:10:25");
 dt.Rows.Add("00:20:15");

 var average = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)(dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => TimeSpan.Parse(row.Field<string>("TotalTime")))
            .Average(ts => ts.Ticks)));

 //00:12:08
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            TimeSpan total = default(TimeSpan);

            foreach (DataRow row in dtChats.Rows)
            {
                //i have no idea what your data looks like coming in in the dataRow. your mileage may vary.
                //for now i'm assuming it contains milliseconds as a string
                total += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Int32.parse(row["TotalTime"].ToString())*1000);
            }

            TimeSpan myAverage = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(total.TotalSeconds / dtChats.Rows.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion for average in `TimeSpan`, it to create a list of `TimeSpan` and use the `Average()` method to get the average `Tick` and generate a new TimeSpan which is the average, for sample:

```
List<TimeSpan> times = new List<TimeSpan>();

foreach (DataRow row in dtChats.Rows)
    times.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(row["TotalTime"].ToString()));

long averageTicks = Convert.ToInt64(list.Average(ts => ts.Ticks));
TimeSpan myAverage = new TimeSpan(averageTicks);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however total always comes back as 00:00 - i can see row has the time in but never gets added